# data of separate PHP array with comma

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, implode

based on a query:

```
  $query = $db->query("SELECT id, email, status, enviados FROM 
  contactos LIMIT 0,500");
```

where I get emails and store them in an array I want to separate them and print them by commas and then put them in a variable, where the result is something like:

```
$ variable = a1, a2, a3;
```

I try to do with implode but it does not work, I was already seeing the other issues but I can not find a solution

this is my code

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT id, email, status, enviados FROM 
contactos LIMIT 0,500");

$count = $query->num_rows;


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $datos_seleccionados[] = array(
        'emails' => $row['email']
    );
}   

for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++) {
    echo implode(",", $datos_seleccionados[$i]);
}
```

Comment: why would you while and then for?

Comment: I did it because with the while I add the data to the array and with the for the idea is to show it separated by commas, which you recommend me if not

Comment: Note that SQL is orderless so using LIMIT without ORDER BY is pretty much meaningless

Comment: If you only need to have a comma separated string i would suggest to look into MySQL GROUP_CONCAT function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it in this way

```
$datos_seleccionados = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
  $datos_seleccionados[] = $row['email'];
}
echo implode(",", $datos_seleccionados);
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not working because you are storing your data into multidimensional array here:

```
$datos_seleccionados[] = array(
        'emails' => $row['email']
    );
```

Using `echo implode(",", $datos_seleccionados[$i]);` inside a `for` look also an issue, it means, you are imploding an array with comma, you can just do it as @Rakesh suggested:

Solution **(i am using this code with some optimization)**:

```
if($count > 0){ // if count exist
    $datos_seleccionados = array(); // initiate
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $datos_seleccionados[] = $row['email'];
    }
    echo implode(",",$datos_seleccionados);
}
else{
    echo "No result found";
}
```

Comment: this be the better answer out of the for/while solutions, and +1 for adding the check

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) for this:

example code:

```
$data = [
    ['title' => 'foo', 'val' => 1],
    ['title' => 'bar', 'val' => 5],
    ['title' => 'foobar', 'val' => 9]
];

echo implode(',', array_column($data, 'val'));
```

here we just group the elements by the key (in this case `val`) and then just implode that returned array

so in your case:

```
echo implode(',', array_column(mysqli_fetch_array($query), 'email'));
```